# Windows XP can't boot

Tags: windows-xp, boot

I'm having a problem. I can't boot my computer. I'll tell what the problem exactly is:

At the beginning, there is a message comes in front of me, when the computer is booting. You know those choices: 'Start Windows Normally, Safe mode etc.' Firstly, i couldn't use my keyboard when those messages came. I reset it. And from BIOS I enabled the USB keyboard. And even if I can use that choices it doesn't let me to ENTER. So when its numbers stops counting, the computer re-starts again. I tried to use the start up CD, but it has no use. What I must do, is there anything I can do from the BIOS?

Comment: We can probably suggest things for the boot but have you tried another keyboard if the ENTER key isn't working/responding or is it just not working at a certain point within the BIOS?

Comment: I have also plugged another USB keyboard. Even if I can use it when choosing Start Windows normally, safe mode etc. when I enter one of those choices, the XP screen comes infront of me, and when is about to start the computer re-starts itself. Thanks for helping and for the message.

Comment: The computer still does not work. I'm thinking about formating the C driver. Is there any other choices you can suggest?

Comment: After enabling the USB keyboard, my old keyboard and also the new keyboard..both works..you know the rest..it does not let it start..

Comment: Do you have 'Last Known Good Configuration (your most recent settings that worked)' option?

Comment: Is this a new install or previously working? Any errors or hardware changes before this started?

Comment: Do you have a Linux LiveCD or extra power supply that you can swap for testing?